# File does not exist exception although file does exist

Tags: java, android-studio, file, uri

I need to user to choose a file from storage. Once user chooses the file I can't do anything with it because it comes back with an exception "File does not exist", although it most certainly does. Permissions are granted and I even take persistent URI permission.
This sample code is not the prettiest, I know but it still shouldn't give me that excpetion I think. Did I write something wrong or that could cause this problem?

Currently this sample code doesn't throw an exception but if statement fails and logs "File does not exist". I need it to pass if statement and call openMap(). If I were to remove the if statement I would get `org.mapsforge.map.reader.header.MapFileException: file does not exist: content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Aestonia.map`

```
    final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> sARL = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Intent data = result.getData();
            assert data != null;
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            File oFile = new File(uri.getPath());
            getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            if (new File(uri.getPath()).exists()){
                openMap(oFile);
            }else{
                Log.w("File", "File does not exist");
            }

        }
    }
});

public void openFileDialog(){
    Intent data = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    data.setType("*/*");
    data = Intent.createChooser(data, "Choose tile");

    sARL.launch(data);
}
```

Comment: And which line throws the exception?  And do you have a stack trace to share?

Comment: FileNotFoundException is thrown.  I don't have stacktrace though

Comment: org.mapsforge.map.reader.header.MapFileException: file does not exist: content:/com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Aestonia.map this is the excpetion but it comes from another library but it is not the cause.

Comment: If you do not have a stack trace then do work on getting one.  Among other things, that would help you answer the question I actually asked (*which line* throws the exception?), which should be of interest to you, too.

Comment: I added to my original question where I got the exception. This does not help me though, no stack trace would as it would just tell me that the file does not exist but I know that it does.

Comment: Perhaps for using this API, it expects you to have some basic knowledge in Java software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the Uri. If I hard code path to the file then everything is fine, but with file choosing intent I can't actually access the real file path, as far as I know. File contents can still be read but I needed the path.

```
File oFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filePath)
```

This did the trick and I got the actual file loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
            File oFile = new File(data.getData().getPath());
            if (oFile.exists()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "exist: "+oFile.exists(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //returns true
                openMap(oFile);
            }else{
                Log.w("File", "File does not exist");
            }
```

Let me know if the problem not solved yet.

Comment: This did not solve my problem sadly.  I still get the same File does not exist. I tried different locations where I select the file from and even tried different file types just in case but nothing.